# Mocha Chai Sinon test inaccessible promise / async / event-emitter

Tags: node.js, testing, promise, sinon, chai

My setup uses `chai`, `sinon`, `chai-sinon`, `chai-as-promised`, `babel` and es6 syntax.

I have the following (reduced) code

```js
// example.js
'use strict';
import EventEmitter from 'events';

class Dispatcher extends EventEmitter {
  send(x) {
    doSomethingAsync() // promise is NOT returned 
      .then(() => {
        this.emit('sent');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.emit('error', err);
      });
  }
}
```

**Note: the promise from doSomethingAsync is NOT returned. (And never will be)**

Here's my (reduced) test file

```
let dispatcher;
let onSent;
let onError;

beforeEach(() => {
  dispatcher = new Dispatcher();

  onSent = sinon.stub();
  onError= sinon.stub();
  dispatcher.on('sent', onSent);
  dispatcher.on('error', onError);
});

describe('send', () => {
  it('should emit "error" on sendFn error instead of "sent"', () => {
    ... set up state for failure ...
    dispatcher.send(...);
    ... What do I do here or how do I wrap the following? ...
    expect(onSent).not.to.have.been.called;
    expect(onError).to.have.been.called;
  });
});
```

I know how to do this if I could return the promise from `doSomethingAsync` as the result of `send`, but that's not the case here. All I have is the knowledge that either the 'sent' or 'error' event will be emitted eventually.

My ideal syntax would look like:

```
expect(onError).to.eventually.have
```

But, that doesn't work. I CAN get a non-erroring version to work as follows simply by wrapping the `expect` in a new promise. But I have no idea why this works.

```
  // This one works for some unknown reason!
  it('should emit "send" on send success', () => {
    ... set up state for success ...
    dispatcher.send(...);
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
       expect(onSent).to.have.been.called;
       expect(onError).not.to.have.been.called;
    });     
  });
```

If I could refactor the code in such a way as to expose the inner promise, then this would be trivial to solve. I have done so countless times in other circumstances. My question here however is **very specifically** how to solve this *exact* pattern; i.e. how to test the side-effects of an inaccessible promise or async code, particularly around event emitters when I cannot refactor the code to expose the promise.

I have tried at least the following just to see if I could trigger the desired send function to complete all its inner callbacks/promises before the test calls the expectations

- wrapping the expectations in a promise
- controlling time using `sinon.useFakeTimers`
- wrapping the expectations in a timeout
- wrapping both send call and expectations in various async/await patterns

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so this is completely ridiculous, but here's a solution that works for both resolved and rejected promises:

```
it('should behave as expected already!', (done) => {
  ... set up for failure or success as desired
  dispatcher.send();
  process.nextTick(() => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      ... expectations ...
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

I think this works because (and I'm totally guessing here!) I assume that thrown errors or rejected promises are processed immediately in the current tick, whereas resolved promises get queued in the next tick. So... the `process.nextTick` ensures that we will queue this function in the next tick, allowing all catches/errors to complete, and the Promise.resolve ensures that it is queued after any already-queued promises are run. Incidentally, you can also switch the order or the nextTick and promise.resolve() and it works just fine.

**NB** If the events are emitted truly asynchronously (e.g. in their own `process.nextTick` then you have to have a 3-level nest. Either Promise-nextTick-promise or nextTick-promise-nextTick.

My word that is messy!

... still better than timeouts though :D

Answer (score 2):

Since the tests are not waiting for the block of code you are testing to resolve/reject the promise, assertions won't work.

And your analysis are all correct but the approach to solve is to resolve promise in assertions.

I have made some changes to your code and made it working.

I have made `doSomethingAsync` to return the promise (I think that is the right solution here)

// Code to be tested

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';

const doSomethingAsync = async (x) => {
  return x;
};

class Dispatcher extends EventEmitter {
  send(x) {
    return doSomethingAsync(x)
      .then((res) => {
         this.emit('sent');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
         this.emit('error', err);
      });
  }
}

export default Dispatcher;
```

// Tests

Option 1: Using await

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import Dispatcher from '../dispatcher';

describe('send', () => {
  let dispatcher;
  let onSent;
  let onError;

  beforeEach(() => {
    dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
    onSent = sinon.stub();
    onError = sinon.stub();
    dispatcher.on('sent', onSent);
    dispatcher.on('error', onError);
  });

  it('Test 1: should emit "error" on sendFn error instead of "sent"', async () => {
    await dispatcher.send('hello');
    expect(onSent.callCount).to.equal(1);
    expect(onError.callCount).to.equal(0);
  });
});
```

// Result

> yarn run spec
>
> send
>       ✓ should emit "error" on sendFn error instead of "sent"
>
> 1 passing (1s)
>
> ✨  Done in 4.18s.

Option 2: With promises

In the test, you can see that I am using an await on `dispatcher.send` or you could also assert using promises as below

```
it('Test 2: should emit "error" on sendFn error instead of "sent"', () => {
  let error = false;
  dispatcher.send('hello').then(() => {
    expect(onSent.callCount).to.equal(1);
    expect(onError.callCount).to.equal(0);
  }).catch(() => {
    error = true;
  })
  expect(error).to.equal(false);
});
```

PS:- If you don't wish to return promise, then first test case (the one using await) will pass & second one will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the answer given by anoop, you could do something like this:

```
function sinonSetUp( eventEmitter )
{
    let onSent = sinon.stub();
    let onError = sinon.stub();
    eventEmitter.on( 'sent', onSent );
    eventEmitter.on( 'error', onError );
    return ({
        onSent: onSent,
        onError: onError,
    });
}

it('emits a sent event', async function()
{
    let dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
    let sinonHandlers = sinonSetUp(dispatcher);
    let promise = dispatcher.send();
    await promise;

    //-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

    //Checking the error event:
    //The way you wish you could do it:
    /* 
    dispatcher.on('error', function(errEventVal)
    {
        expect(errEventVal).to.be.undefined; 
    }); 
    */

    //The way you have to do it:
    //args[0] gets the returned arguments, if any exist
    let errEventArgs = sinonHandlers.onError.args[0]; 
    expect(errEventArgs).to.be.undefined;

    //-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

    //Checking the sent event:
    //The way you wish you could do it:
    /* 
    dispatcher.on('sent', function(sentEventVal)
    { 
        expect(sentEventVal).not.to.be.undefined; 
    }); 
    */

    //The way you have to do it:
    //If args[0] exists, then the value will be in args[0][0]
    //See the documentation for sinonjs.
    let sentEventArgs = sinonHandlers.onSent.args[0];
    expect(sentEventArgs).not.to.be.undefined;
    let sentEventVal = sentEventArgs[0];
    expect(sentEventVal).not.to.be.undefined;
});
```